# connect to a k3s container with kubectl

Tags: java, docker, testcontainers, k3s

I have been using a k3s cluster running in a docker container with testcontainers to run integration tests.

I would like to put a breakpoint in my tests and inspect the k3s cluster with kubectl.
When the execution stops on the breakpoint, I run the following commands:

```
kubectl config set-cluster my-k3s-cluster --server=https://localhost:52067
kubectl config set-context my-k3s --cluster=my-k3s-cluster
kubectl config use-context my-k3s
```

But when I run any command (eg: `kubectl get pods`), the cluster asks me for credentials.

Is there any way to start the k3s cluster disabling authentication?

Answer (score 0):

I worked this problem around by directly executing into the k3s container. Once there, I can run kubectl commands and interact with the various resources.